# Drawing upon Listview in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, drawing

I want to draw something upon in listview controls. You think, you have two layer, the first layer has readonly richtextboxes and images, the second layer has swapchainpanel to draw something. How can make I transparent swapchainpanel. Here is my xaml.

```
<Page 
    x:Class="AppDemo.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:AppDemo"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ic="using:MatchaDemo.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="Page_Loaded">
    <Page.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,10,0,0"  
                Source="Assets/lemon_cut_drop_citrus_65816_1920x1200.jpg"
                                   Height="400" Width= "{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=NoteList}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TextTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <RichEditBox  IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="0,10,0,0" 
                             Height="400" Width= "{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=NoteList}"></RichEditBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="GapTemplate">
            <StackPanel Height="20"></StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <local:NoteTypeTemplateSelector x:Key="NoteTypeTemplateSelector"
        TextTemplate="{StaticResource TextTemplate}"
        ImageTemplate="{StaticResource ImageTemplate}"
        GapTemplate="{StaticResource GapTemplate}"></local:NoteTypeTemplateSelector>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <ToggleSwitch 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                Toggled="ModeSwitch_Toggled" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Name="ModeSwitch">
                Draw Mode
            </ToggleSwitch>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="NoteList" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ds}" CanDrag="True" 
        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource NoteTypeTemplateSelector}">
        </ListView>
        <SwapChainPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="DxPanel" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"      ManipulationMode="All"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: You don't have any question mark in your post. That's a good indicator that you haven't really asked a question. What is your question?

Comment: since you asked question about drawing listview in WPF, it is not related to UWP, I remove the UWP tag in this question.